# NSLog crashes with certain NSURL- iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurl, nslog

Here is my code,where the crash occurs:-

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "http://files.parsetfss.com/fa80bc63-88d4-412d-a478-2451cffc92a9/tfss-1d2a321d-b02e-4745-a589-e31536f648df-XXXXX%20CAT15%2030.p0001.jpg")
NSLog("Loading page with URL: \(URL)")
```

The app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: @MartinR, my bad, I didn't paid too much attention. The URL is kinda truncated for me. It stops exactly before the %20.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first argument of `NSLog()` is a *format string*, and contains
[format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) (starting with `%`) which are expanded by the
following variable argument list. In your case `%20C` is a format specifier, but
no matching argument is supplied. That causes undefined behavior,
it can crash or produce incomplete or wrong output.

If you want to use `NSLog()` then a general safe method is

```
NSLog("%@", "Loading page with URL: \(URL)")
```

In this particular case,

```
NSLog("Loading page with URL: %@", URL)
```

works as well, since `NSURL` is a `NSObject` subclass and can be used
with the `%@` format.

Comment: Bull's Eye! Thanks a'lot Martin, didn't knew that %20C is the culprit ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should use println instead of NSLog.

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "http://files.parsetfss.com/fa80bc63-88d4-412d-a478-2451cffc92a9/tfss-1d2a321d-b02e-4745-a589-e31536f648df-XXXXX%20CAT15%2030.p0001.jpg")!
println("Loading page with URL: \(URL)")
```

I have added  the option sign ! at the end to unwrap.

Comment: If the OP is using Swift 2.0, `println`has been replaced with `print`

Comment: There can be good reasons to use NSLog even in a Swift program. For example, it does not produce garbage output when called from multiple threads, and it prints a timestamp.

Comment: Is it? I am still using println. it works fine :-) Although thanks for the information @Ollie

Comment: `I am still using println. it works fine` Because you're using Swift 1, not Swift 2.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution TechBee, but I prefer to use NSLog(), but appreciate your effort +1.

Comment: Note that `NSLog` appears in the device log but `print` doesn't.