# stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters acts weird on spaces

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do a safe HTTP request in Swift, but as soon as I try to escape a string with a space with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())` (why is that function name so long, seriously), it seems to add a lot of whitespace and some hexadecimal-like notation:

```
"abc"   -> "abc"                       (Looks fine)
"abc "  -> "abc2                       (No closing quotes?)
"abc a" -> "abc              0x0p+0"   (?!)
```

I honestly can't put a finger on what's happening

#### EDIT

My code to get this is this:

```swift
func getLocations(query: String) -> String {
    let safeQuery = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    NSLog("query: \(query) -> \(safeQuery)")
}
```

Which is called like

```swift
foo.getLocations(textField.text!)
```

Where textField is a text field in a view.

Comment: How are you printing these results, NSLog, print? Also please show an example of the faulty URL before and after.

Comment: It seems like the whitespaces may not actually be white spaces but some other character which just appears as white space in your editor?

Comment: @EricD. I'm using NSLog to print it, and I'm just putting the string before the arrow into it. I'll edit the question to show how I do that.

Comment: @PradeepK I'm getting the string from the text property of an UITextField, so that should be fine

Comment: Do you type the strings in the text field or is it populated from somewhere else and then you read it from the text field?

Comment: @PradeepK I type them into the simulator myself

Comment: `"abc a".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())` has the same strange result when printed using NSLog and string interpolation

Comment: Same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335885/nslog-crashes-with-certain-nsurl-ios-9-2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of your usage of NSLog.

With this:

```
NSLog("query: \(query) -> \(safeQuery)")
```

you get this:

> query: abc a -> abc              0x0p+0

because you're using NSLog with Swift's string interpolation. This doesn't work well.

Use NSLog's own interpolation system instead, where each `%@` will be replaced by the items provided, in order:

```
NSLog("query: %@ -> %@", query, safeQuery)
```

prints:

> query: abc a -> abc%20a

Comment: I totally overlooked that NSLog expects a format string. Indeed, using NSLog properly, or using print, solves the issue. Thanks!