# How can you mark a method that it is fatal, like `fatalError`?

Tags: swift, fatal-error

We have a special logging function that represents a particular type of crash, and as such, internally it calls `fatalError`.  However, unlike `fatalError`, when we use it in a `guard` statement, it still complains we haven't exited the scope of the `guard`.

I checked the source code and `fatalError` returns `-> Never` so I tried that, but that didn't work either.  I also didn't see any attributes applied to it that may be telling the compiler 'this is the end of the road'.

So is it possible to have your own `fatalError`-like method?

```
func myFatalError(memberName:String = #function) -> Never {
    let message = "Failed in \(memberName)" 
    NSLog(message)
    fatalError(message)
}
```

Comment: Your method works when I try it in a `guard` statement. What specifically is happening when you try it?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka mine won’t even compile.  Lemme try cleaning the project, derived data,, etc.

Comment: `-> Never` *is* the correct way to mark such a function.

Comment: (Unrelated to this question, but note that using anything but a string literal as the format argument of NSLog is unsafe, better use `NSLog("Failed in %s", memberName)` )

Comment: Good to know!  This was just dummy code I typed here in the window. Do you have more information on why that is unsafe?

Comment: @MarqueIV: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35336296/1187415 for an example.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that case!  Thanks!

Comment: Yep! Was a problem with Xcode.  It was showing an error, but restarting it made it go away.  Can someone here post an answer (or close this) so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by others, the issue was something on my machine specifically.  The following (returning 'Never') works as expected.

```
func myFatalError() -> Never {
    print("Doing something fatal")
}
```